# How to put values of objects from an array into a string

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make my sales app send a customer a message with all the purchased items with their prices. The purchased items  are stored in the dp, each item with its quantity and price.

I have fetched all the purchased items, but I can't put the items' name and prices into a single sting - which is the message to be send to the customer.

Below is my items array object

```
$order = App\Order::find($id);
$items = $order->orderItems;

$item = OrderItem::where('order_id', $order->id)->first();

 $message = $order->code . " confirmed. ".$order->customer->name ." ". $order->customer->vehicle_plate . " has paid KES ".$order->amount."  for ".$item->quantity." ".$item->item->unit->name." of ".$item->item->name." at ".$order->updated_at->format('d/m/Y h:i a');
```

This message has the first item of the order. I need a single message with all order items.

Comment: You can iterate through all items and concatenated the generated text for each product to a variable, then display that variable. Let's say you have a function `getItemOrderText` which returns the message for a single item. You could then do something like `$message .= getItemOrderText($currentItem) . '<br />'`.

Comment: Works like magic. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can concatenate item data by iterating through the loop

```
$order = App\Order::find($id);
$items = $order->orderItems;

$item = OrderItem::where('order_id', $order->id)->first();
$message = $order->code . " confirmed. ".$order->customer->name ." ".     $order->customer->vehicle_plate . " has paid KES ".$order->amount."  for ";

foreach($item as $item_value){
    $message .=  $item_value->quantity." ".$item_value->item->unit->name." of ".$item_value->item->name;
 }
$message .= " at ".$order->updated_at->format('d/m/Y h:i a');

echo $message;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
$order = App\Order::find(14);
$items = $order->orderItems;

$itemMessage = "";
foreach($items as $item){
    $itemMessage .= $item->quantity." ".$item->item->unit->name." ".$item->item->name." ";
}

$message = $order->code . " confirmed. ".$order->customer->name ." ". $order->customer->vehicle_plate . " has paid KES ".$order->amount."  for ".$itemMessage." at ".$order->updated_at->format('d/m/Y h:i a');

return $message;
```